# Порядок и метод реализации приложения тянущего из MS SQLв ListView

Tags: android, sql-server

Необходимо создать приложение которое, будет тянуть информацию в `listview` с базы данных MS SQL на хостинге (пока что бесплатном для теста). При том, база данных имеет иерархическую структуру. То есть в приложение при нажатии на один из пунктов `listview` открывается новое `activity` c еще несколькими пунктами `listview` и так далее.

Прошу подсказать какой порядок и методы реализации даной задачи. Подробно уже буду пытаться разобраться сам. Больше интересует реализация связи приложения с базой MS SQL и выгрузка данных с базы в форме `listview`.

На данный момент есть готовая структура базы данный MS SQL с ключами на бесплатном хостинге, и в android studio готовое графическое оформление с `listview`.

Answer (score 0):

Подбираете архитектурный шаблон, берете для интерфейса TreeView(не знаю, есть ли на Android, но элемент нужный многим). Пишем, гуглим, тестируем.

Comment: Изначально TreeView рассматривал, но отказался от этой идеи, так как насколько я правильно понял, TreeView реализует дерево в одном activity в форме выпадающих списков как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271772/android-treeview (других примеров не находил). А мне надо что бы при нажатии на пункт списка открывалось новое окно.